# Selenium unexpectedly having issues

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have been using selenium now for a while on a number of projects.

With code that was running I am now receiving the following error:

```
    C:\Users\%USER%\Miniconda\python.exe C:/Users/%USER%/PycharmProjects/c_r/quick_debug.py
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Users/%USER%/PycharmProjects/c_r/quick_debug.py", line 17, in <module>
        c.setUp()
      File "C:\Users\%USER%\PycharmProjects\c_r\c.py", line 40, in setUp
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
      File "C:\Users\%USER%\Miniconda\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 67, in __init__
        desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
      File "C:\Users\%USER%\Miniconda\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 87, in __init__
        self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
      File "C:\Users\%USER%\Miniconda\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 141, in start_session
        'desiredCapabilities': desired_capabilities,
      File "C:\Users\%USER%\Miniconda\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 201, in execute
        self.error_handler.check_response(response)
      File "C:\Users\%USER%\Miniconda\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 181, in check_response
        raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: unrecognized Blink revision: 3b3c00f2d95c45cca18ab944acced413fb759311
      (Driver info: chromedriver=2.10.267521,platform=Windows NT 6.3 x86_64)


    Process finished with exit code 1
```

where `c.setUp()` is:

```
def setUp(self):
   self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

Again -  this is code that WAS running and I am unsure how to this "Unrecognized blink revision" error.

Nothing has consciously changed.

Thank you for any pointers

Answer (score 39, accepted):

After having a quick look at the [source code](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/31b6a93e15c029f5ccba9b4a9af47366ad5205f0/chrome/test/chromedriver/chrome/browser_info.cc#103), I think this is a compatibility issue between ChromeDriver and Chrome itself - I suspect your *Chrome auto-updated and now is too new for ChromeDriver 2.10*.

In other words: **update ChromeDriver**, latest is currently [2.19](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads).

Comment: Worked for me, easily test this option by pointing to the new ChromeDriver.  IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\your\path");

Comment: I was facing the same issue and wasn't able to understand the response here. 

I had issues finding where the chromeDriver is installed. But found it. So when you say updating the chromeDriver its the chromedriver that's located in your selenium folder. Just replace that with the latest version that made it work.

Comment: I had the same issue it worked for me. I'v updated chromedriver to ChromeDriver 2.2. I have selenium==2.51.1, PyVirtualDisplay==0.2 and Google Chrome 51.0.2704.106  on ubuntu 14.04