# Chome opens for a split second then closes using selenium webdriver

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, chrome-web-driver

I’m setting up chromedriver (win32) on visual studio using C#, I have firefox and it works great. I have downloaded the chromedriver.exe and set the PATH in windows to its location (C:...misc...\Selenium Webdriver\chromedriver) as the book “selenium recepies in C sharp” suggests. I am able to open up the driver via cmd and see the port. I have also used the NuGet package manager to get the chromewebdriver there.  I have looked at this [link](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/help/chrome-doesn-t-start) with no success.

Chrome open for a split second and then closes.

My code.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;

namespace UnitTestProject1
{
    [TestClass]
    public class BrowserTest
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void ChromeTest()
        {
            IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
        }
    }
}
```

I’m willing to remove everything and start from scratch if I’ve botched the install somewhere along the way. Any help would be great.

EDIT: I have uninstalled and reinstalled chrome also.

Comment: My guess is that Selenium closes the browser at the end of a test. Try putting in Selenium.WaitForPageToLoad("3000");

Comment: When I replace Chromedriver with Firefoxdriver it works fine and leaves a firefox window open. I tried `Thread.Sleep(100000);` as you suggested to let it wait but no luck. It still immediately crashes.

Comment: If it is crashing, debug it... what error is it throwing?

Comment: An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in WebDriver.dll but was not handled in user code  
Additional information: unknown error: unrecognized Blink revision: 07d51ee3ea74c918d7eb65938af89e443bf95a3a

Comment: That's the error I get from `IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();` I'm also getting a command prompt popup now saying `Starting ChromeDriver <v2.10.267521> on port 51244 Only local connections are allowed`. Any help would be great with this, can't make sense of it.

Comment: Maybe this could help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32792739/selenium-unexpectedly-having-issues

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply but I was able to follow the answer @L.Bar gave below and that worked for me. Thank you though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;

namespace UnitTestProject1
{
    [TestClass]
    public class BrowserTest
    {
    string DRIVER_PATH = @"C:...misc...\Selenium Webdriver\chromedriver";

        [TestMethod]
        public void ChromeTest()
        {
            IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(DRIVER_PATH);
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This fixed it. Thanks a million! It's always something simple :)

Comment: What was the issue resolution? I am having the same issue. I added the source which is `Environment.CurrentDirectory` and it still closes.

Answer (score 0):

I am new to selenium. As per tutorial I installed Web Driver for Google Chrome i.e WebDriverChromedriver. On running the sample program I got the same issue.
Then I installed "Selenium.Chrome.WebDriver" package from Nugetpackage. And my program got executed successfully.

[image]