# Getting InavlidOperationException error while running selenium code

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am new to Selenium and I get the following error on running a piece of code. Can you please help me debug the issue. The error code is available in the image shared. I am running the test on Win 10 using VS 12 ultimate.  [Error]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7pPj.jpg

Error line:
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

Error:
InavlidOperationException:
unknown error: unrecognized Blink revision: 9fd42dd40d33146ff9afd92f51714f0426c1247c

(Driver info: chromedriver=2.10.267521,platform=Windows NT 6.3 x86_64)

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SeleniumThird
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the complete traceback.

Comment: @alecxe just edited the post. Just check if you need more information.

Comment: duplicate post ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32792739/selenium-unexpectedly-having-issues

Comment: what is your chrome version? pls refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32792739/selenium-unexpectedly-having-issues

Comment: @parishodak  - Solution in  stackoverflow.com/questions/32792739/ worked for me. Thank you very much for helping :)